# Rules for invocation of onfocus method

Tags: javascript

In the mass of JavaScript I'm trying to support, I have over 300 uses like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="x" value="y" style="stuffweshouldhaveincss", class="z"
 onfocus="javascript:$.fn_StoreExistData(this.value)"
 onchange="javascript:$.BigSection.TraceChange('aa','bb','cc')" />
```

In many cases, the StoreExistData function does get called; the general idea is to store the value that is currently in the field and revert to it if the field fails the validation in the "TraceChange" function.  My problem is that sometimes the StoreExistData function seems to work fine -- the validation routine detects an error, pops up a message, and restores the corresponding field to its previous value.

Sometimes, it restores it to a previous value from some other field.  It appears, based on setting breakpoints in the Chrome debugger, that sometimes the StoreExistData function is not getting called.  That would explain the use of previously stored values, so I'm left pondering what could cause the function call to get skipped for some fields (or in some situations) and not other times.  Can someone point me to things to check out for this?

Comment: Have you tried using a general event handler (eg. `$("input[type=text]).on("focus", function(e) { $.fn_StoreExistData(e.target.value) });` instead of inline `onfocus`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think that would work?  The invocations in the form I have work in some instances and not in others; this indicates to me that this way of invoking the routine is valid.  There are many, many, (many, MANY) different ways to do things, I am not looking to just change to another way.  I am hoping someone can point me to possible reasons why some of the cases I have don't work so that I can feel like I'm fixing something instead of just trying something different.

Comment: Are all of your inputs `text` fields? Chrome doesn't support :focus on `checkbox` and `radio` inputs.

Comment: Yes, at least all of the ones I'm worried about are text fields.  The idea is to save a value to restore on failure to validate, and there isn't much validation on checkbox and radio buttons (at least in this system),.